# Eloquent Feature of Laravel Doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to laravel and I want to use eloquent feature of it but I got an error.

in routes.php

```
Route::get('/contact', function(){

    $books = Books::all();

    return View::make('pages.contact')->with('pages.contact', $books);
});
```

and in my contact.blade.php
I wrote

```
  @foreach ($books as $book)
         <p> {{ $book -> title}}</p>
  @endforeach
```

But it doesn't see $books variable. Please help me. How can I fix it? When I say that

return $books; it works. I can get values from database but eloquent doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the docs of Laravel? What version are u using? Assuming you are using Laravel 5.2 can you try to do this?

```
return view('pages.contact', ['books' => $books]);
or
return view('pages.contact')->with('books', $books);
```

You can iterate a collection in a blade template. Also you can transform that eloquent collection to an array or a json (I usually use this when I use ajax)

> LARAVEL DOCS: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views

Comment: I want to ask one more question. I wrote base urls like "href=<?php echo asset('images/filter-thumbs/p10.jpg'); ?> " is there a way to say something like that src=<?php echo asset({{ $book -> file}}); ?>